# How to operate queue in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a error message service for my spring project.
here is my idea.

1) I will store a queue in session.
2) will access queue on template if anything is in queue print it.

so i now the stuff like session and queue.
but i dont have idea how to loop the queue in thymeleaf and use its poll method to print errors so if page is refreshed it should not display any error since it was already fetched.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it. Loop based on the size of queues and use the poll() method to dequeue it.

```
<p th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(1, session.queues.size())}" th:text="${session.queues.poll()}"></p>
```